# multiple containers on top of each other and navigate between them

Tags: dart, flutter

i want to create a page which have for example 12 containers on top of each other .. and when i click on next .. container number 12 will go and 11 is displayed .. and so on till i end all of them ..

Something similar to this screenshot:

[image]

the page will have 2 buttons .. next and previous .. so i can go to next or previous .. and so on

is there is a way to do this in flutter? plugin or something?

Comment: check this package : https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_swiper

Comment: @diegoveloper thanks alot! i know this package .. but it works more with swiping when i want to control them by next back button :(